# android retrieving data from mysql database displaying it in new activity?

Tags: android, mysql

Getting error in in the second parameter of `putExtra()` method...`username cannot be resolved`.Two method are from different class one is Mainactivity.java and second one is Backgroundworker.java extending Asyntask?I want to display the registration details(name,phone no.,blood group etc) in a new activity that is home when the user logs in or registers in the app.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
    Button b1,b2;
    EditText ed1,ed2;

    TextView tx1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        ed1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        ed2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    }

    public void OnLogin(View view) {
        String username = ed1.getText().toString();
        String password = ed2.getText().toString();
        String type = "login";
        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
        backgroundWorker.execute(type, username, password);
   }

   public void onButtonClick(View v ) {
       if(v.getId() == R.id.button1)
       {
           Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Register.class);
           startActivity(i);
       }
    }      

}

public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    BackgroundWorker (Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type = params[0];
        String login_url = "http://retiform-power.000webhostapp.com/login.php";
        String register_url = "http://retiform-power.000webhostapp.com/register.php";
        if(type.equals("login")) {
            try {
                String user_name = params[1];
                String password = params[2];
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result="";
                String line="";
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if(type.equals("register")){

             try {
                 String name = params[1];
                 String password = params[2];
                 String aadhar = params[3];
                 String phone = params[4];
                 String blodgrp = params[5];
                 String secrthnt = params[6];
                 URL url = new URL(register_url);
                 HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                 httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                 httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                 httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                 OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                 BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                 String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("Name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode("Paswrd","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode("Aadhar","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(aadhar,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode("Phone","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(phone,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode("Bldgrp","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(blodgrp,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode("Secrthnt","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(secrthnt,"UTF-8");
                 bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                 bufferedWriter.flush();
                 bufferedWriter.close();
                 outputStream.close();
                 InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                 BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                 String result="";
                 String line="";
                 while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                     result += line;
                 }
                 bufferedReader.close();
                 inputStream.close();
                 httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                 return result;
             } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {            
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        if(result.contentEquals("success")) {

            Intent i=new Intent(context, Home.class);
            i.putExtra("name", username);
            context.startActivity(i);

          } 
        else
        {
            Toast toast= Toast.makeText(context, "Email or password is wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

Comment: post your full code

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, could you provide some code of your specific problem. That will help other members to understand your 

problem better, at the time, you will give them a context of your issue. Please, check these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and 

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

> 1) For me that's the most simple way passing parameters to async task is like this

```
// To call the async task do it like this

String username = ed1.getText().toString();

String password = ed2.getText().toString();

String type = "login";

String[] myTaskParams = { username, password, type };

myAsyncTask = new BackgroundWorker ().execute(myTaskParams);
```

**Declare and use the async task like here**

```
  private class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        String userName, password, type;

 @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

           ......

        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String...pParams) 
        {


            //

              userName=pParams[0];    
              password=pParams[1];
              type    =pParams[2];    
          ....
    }         

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


                alertDialog.setMessage(result);
                if(result.contentEquals("success")) {

                    Intent i=new Intent(context, Home.class);
                    i.putExtra("name", username);
                    context.startActivity(i);

                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Change `doInBackground()` methods `return-type` from `String` to `ArrayList<String>`

**2.** Change `onPostExecute()` methods `parameter` from `String` to `ArrayList<String>`

**3.** In `doInBackground()`, add `username` and `result` string to ArrayList `resultList`

**4.** In `onPostExecute()`, get `username` and `result` string from ArrayList `results`

**5.** Finally, pass `username` to `Home` class using `Intent`.

**Update your `BackgroundWorker` class as below:**

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;

    BackgroundWorker (Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params) {

        // Required to pass username and result >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
        ArrayList<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();

        String type = params[0];
        String login_url = "http://retiform-power.000webhostapp.com/login.php";
        String register_url = "http://retiform-power.000webhostapp.com/register.php";
        if(type.equals("login")) {
            try {
                String user_name = params[1];
                String password = params[2];
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result="";
                String line="";
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                // Add user_name and result string to resultList >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
                resultList.add(user_name);
                resultList.add(result);

                return resultList;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if(type.equals("register")){

             try {
                 String name = params[1];
                 String password = params[2];
                 String aadhar = params[3];
                 String phone = params[4];
                 String blodgrp = params[5];
                 String secrthnt = params[6];
                 URL url = new URL(register_url);
                 HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                 httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                 httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                 httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                 OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                 BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                 String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("Name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode("Paswrd","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode("Aadhar","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(aadhar,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode("Phone","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(phone,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode("Bldgrp","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(blodgrp,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode("Secrthnt","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(secrthnt,"UTF-8");
                 bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                 bufferedWriter.flush();
                 bufferedWriter.close();
                 outputStream.close();
                 InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                 BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                 String result="";
                 String line="";
                 while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                     result += line;
                 }
                 bufferedReader.close();
                 inputStream.close();
                 httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                 // Add name and result string to resultList >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
                 resultList.add(name);
                 resultList.add(result);

                 return resultList;
              } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> results) {   

        // Get username and result string >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
        String username = results.get(0);
        String result = results.get(1);         

        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {

            Intent i = new Intent(context, Home.class);
            i.putExtra("name", username);
            context.startActivity(i);
        } else {
            Toast toast= Toast.makeText(context, "Email or password is wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

Hope this will help~